# In typescript, is it possible to benefit from eslint no-relative-parent-imports for values, but still be allowed to import types from parents?

Tags: typescript, eslint

I like to use the [`imports/no-relative-parent-imports`](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/no-relative-parent-imports.md) eslint rule to keep the dependencies between different parts of the code clear, and the code easily testable.

With typescript, I stumble upon this issue: I still need to import types from parents to do dependency injection (unless I duplicate the types for each usage)

For example, if I just translate the code from [the rule's documentation](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/no-relative-parent-imports.md) to typescript, it becomes this :

```
// ./add.ts
export default function add (numbers: number[]): number {
  return numbers.reduce((sum, n) => sum + n, 0)
}

export type Add = typeof add

// three.ts
import { Add } from '../add' // <--- Relative import still needed to implement
                             //      dependency injection 

export default function three(add: Add) : number {
  return add([1, 2]);
}
```

Of course this adaptation wouldn't pass the rule, because of the relative import.

The only way I see would be duplicating the type, which would work because of the structural nature of typescript, but that would be cumbersome on a big project.

Is there a rule that enforces dependency injection, while letting me import types declared in the dependencies ? Because I need the interfaces, function parameters types, etc...

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to implement this with [eslint-plugin-local-rules](https://github.com/cletusw/eslint-plugin-local-rules).

First, install the `local-rules` plugin :

```
npm install eslint-plugin-local-rules --save-dev
```

Use it to implement a rule that achieve the desired purpose :

```
// eslint-local-rules.cjs

'use strict'

module.exports = {
  'no-relative-parent-imports': {
    meta: {
      docs: {
        description: 'disallow identifiers',
        category: 'Possible Errors',
        recommended: false,
      },
      schema: [],
    },
    create: function (context) {
      return {
        ImportDeclaration: function (node) {
          const tsNode = context.parserServices.esTreeNodeToTSNodeMap.get(node)

          if (tsNode.importClause.isTypeOnly) {
            return
          }

          if (tsNode.moduleSpecifier.text.includes('..')) {
            context.report({
              node: node,
              message: 'Import from relative parent. Une `import type` for types and dependency injection for values.',
            })
          }
        },
      }
    },
  },
}
```

And finally configure eslint to use it.
Minimal configuration to do so :

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": [
    "local-rules"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "local-rules/no-relative-parent-imports": "error"
  }
}
```